# Find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the image of $f(x)=\frac {x^2+ax+1}{x^2+x+1}$ is included in $[0,2]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the image of $f(x)=\frac {x^2+ax+1}{x^2+x+1}$ is included in $[0,2]$.

My attempt:

We have: $f'(x)=-\frac{(a-1)(x^2-1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\implies x = 1$ and $x = -1$ points of extrema.

then for $a\geq 1$:

[image]

so then $$2-a=0\implies a=2$$ and $$\frac {a+2}3=2\implies a=4.$$

and for $a\leq1:$

[image]

so then $$2-a=3\implies a=-1$$ and $$\frac {a+2}3=0\implies a=-2.$$

Now my answers are in the type of interval. How do I know which interval to choose?

Comment: Why do you solve this problems with calculus?

Comment: @imranfat yeah. me too, but I have to find $a$ without desmos

Comment: @ChristianF why not

Comment: Because it goes easier without it when you have rational function which is ratio of two quadratics.

Comment: if $-1$ is your max and $1$ is your min, then $2-a \le 0$ and $\frac {2+a}{3} \ge 2$ giving $a\ge 2$  and $a\ge 4$  if both are true then the condition which covers both is $a\ge 4$  Then we examine $1$ as max and $-1$ as min, giving $a\le -2$

Comment: "How do I know which interval to choose?"  Umm... by testing them and choosing the ones that work?

Comment: As the question is written I would just say $a=1$ makes the fraction $1$ for all $x$, so it works.  It didn't ask for all the $a$ that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)$ is equal to $\dfrac{(a-1)(x^2-1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$ so the extremes  are independent of a and taken at $x=\pm 1$. This extremes are $\dfrac{2\pm a}{3}$ It follows $0\le a\le 2$

Answer (score 4):

Lemma: If $x^2+mx+n\geq 0$ for all $x$ then discriminant $m^2-4n \leq 0$.

---

First note that $x^2+x+1>0$ for all $x$ (since discriminant =$-3$)

$$0\leq f(x)\leq 2 \implies 0\leq x^2+ax+1\leq 2x^2+2x+2$$

- From $0\leq x^2+ax+1$ we get $a^2-4\leq 0$ so $|a|\leq 2$ so $\boxed{-2\leq a\leq 2}$.
- From $x^2+ax+1\leq 2x^2+2x+2$ we have $0\leq x^2+(2-a)x+1$ so $(a-2)^2-4\leq 0$ so $|a-2|\leq 2$ so $\boxed{0\leq a\leq 4}$.

Thus $a\in[0,2]$.

Comment: Good answer, you might want to add that you used the Discriminant of a quadratic term. It took me a while to figure out.

Comment: Indeed, man.. but it's not what I actually wanted...

Comment: @C.Cristi: "it's not what I actually wanted" - why not? It seems to me that it is *exactly* what you asked for. If it is not, please edit your question and clarify what you want (and why this answer is not what you want).

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{(a-1)x}{x^2+x+1}$$

and note that $f(x) \in [0,2]$ is equivalent to $(a-1)\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \in [-1,1]$.

Notice that $\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \in [-1,1]$:

$$\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \le 1 \iff 0 \le x^2+1$$

$$\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \ge -1 \iff 0 \le x^2+2x + 1$$

Now, if $a \in [0,2]$ then $|a-1| \le 1$ so

$$|a-1|\underbrace{\left|\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}\right|}_{\le 1} \le 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Conversely, if $(a-1)\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \in [-1,1], \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then in particular for $x = -1$ we get $1-a \in [-1,1]$ which implies $a \in [0,2]$.

We conclude $f(x) \in [0,2], \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $a \in [0,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing well. The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{(a-1)(x^2-1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=(1-a)\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}
$$
Leaving aside $1-a$, the fraction is negative for $|x|<1$.

If $1-a>0$, the function has a maximum at $-1$ and a minimum at $1$. The situation is reversed for $1-a<0$. For $a=1$ the function is constant and satisfies the requirement.

Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=1$, we just need to compute
$$
f(-1)=2-a
\qquad
f(1)=\frac{2+a}{3}
$$
Thus we must have
$$
\begin{cases}
1-a>0 \\[4px]
2-a\le2 \\[4px]
2+a\ge0
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
1-a<0 \\[4px]
2-a\ge0 \\[4px]
2+a\le6
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad a=1
$$
Solving this gives $0\le a\le 2$.